# How can GitHub's GraphQL API can be consumed from Java?

Tags: java, github, graphql, github-api

I'd like to consume GitHub's GraphQL API from Java and after extensive searching I was not able to find a library or other solution which lets me do this in an easy to use way.

The official docs do not detail how this can be done either.

How can I consume GitHub's v4 API? I'd like to generate code based on the API itself so I can use it in a programmatic way.

Comment: This is a pretty broad question. What part are you having trouble with? GraphQL itself? Please read [ask].

Comment: I think it is a pretty specific question. I want to consume GitHub's v4 API using Java with code generation. How can this be more specific?

Comment: "I was not able to find a library … which lets me do this in an easy way." I'm certain that GraphQL libraries exist for Java. Are you specifically looking for a GitHub-via-GraphQL library? (Note that asking us to find or recommend off-site resources is off-topic here.) "The official docs do not detail how this can be done either." Do you need a GraphQL tutorial? There are plenty of these online. "How can I consume GitHub's v4 API?" By using GraphQL against the documented endpoints. Again, a tutorial might be helpful. Please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic] and then [ask].

Comment: I've read all the tutorials and the documentation. I have created my own GraphQL API as an exercise, but there is no info about how to consume  GraphQL APIs.  *"By using GraphQL against the documented endpoints."* <-- I know that I have to do this, I tried out the GitHub Explorer but what I want is a programmatic approach where I can write queries/mutations in code.

Comment: Based on your comments I think your question can be simplified. Forget about GitHub and its API: your question appears to be, "How can I efficiently build GraphQL queries in Java?" (As far as I know, GraphQL itself can be queried using any HTTP client: the challenge is in building query strings efficiently.) Unfortunately, I don't know the answer to this question.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the info anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you try out open source Insomnia. It gives you the ability to automatically generate Java code from your GraphQL queries for the OkHttp library to use.

For example:

The following graphQL query...

```
query GetIssues($client: String!
                             ) {
  organization(login: $client) {
    name
    repositories(last: 10) {
      edges {
        cursor
        node {
          name
          url
          description
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

...will generate the following Java snippet...

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/graphql");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "{\"query\":\"query GetIssues($client: String!) {\\n  organization(login: $client) {\\n    name\\n    repositories(last: 10) {\\n      edges {\\n        cursor\\n        node {\\n          name\\n          url\\n          description\\n        }\\n      }\\n    }\\n  }\\n}\\n\",\"variables\":{\"client\":\"AniTrend\"},\"operationName\":\"GetIssues\"}");
Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://api.github.com/graphql")
  .post(body)
  .addHeader("authorization", "Bearer YOU_BEARER_AUTH_HERE")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Then if you use what you know about GraphQL variables in the queries and mate that to what you know about Java variables, you should then be able to modify the `RequestBody` strings. It's a simple and dirty solution that has loads of room for improvement, something I am exploring currently as well. I'll revisit this as I develop a more robust solution.